# PHP split,substr an email in different part

Tags: php, arrays, regex, split

I need to split an email different parts:

Exemple: PRgdg53366Joe@hotmail.com ==>  |PRgdg|53366|Joe|@hotmail.com| ==>

|String|5 digit|String|@hotmail.com| .

I dont know what is easiest way to do it. With regular expression with preg_match() or Split/Substr/explode.

```
$parts = explode('@', "PRgdg53366Joe@hotmail.com");

$name = $parts[0];
$mailserver = $parts[1];
```

I dont know how to split "PRgdg5336Joe" in 3 part.
*Details : |Unlimited number of character| Exactly 5 Digit |Unlimited number of character | @mailserver.com|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do this and use capturing for each part.

```
preg_match("/(.*)(\d{5})(.*)/", $parts[0], $matches);
```

Now `$matches` will be an array containing the full match in `$matches[0]` and the three parts you need in `$matches[1]` and on.